# Update a nested state in a reducer React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, immutability, reducers

I'm using redux with reactjs. Here's my reducer state :

```
{
 XSAUZHNAKZJ : //id User
  {
   AZRAERAZEAZ : //id Conversation - always one object 
    {
     timestamp : 123123123,
     lastMessage : "hello"
    }
  },
 BLZEJARNAELKR : //id User
  {
   AANALZKJAZ : //id Conversation - always one object
    {
     timestamp : 123123123,
     lastMessage : "hello"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to update the reducer and add a key/value ('name' : joe) just after lastMessage. I have the value of name (ex : joe) and an id User (ex : XSAUZHNAKZJ) in my action.payload. Here's my code, but it seems that I'm not doing right.

```
export default function(state={},action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'GET_USER_INFO':
      var tempState = Object.assign({}, state);
      var conversation = tempState[action.payload.key];
      var conversationDetail = conversation[Object.keys(conversation)[0]];
      conversationDetail['name']=action.payload.val().name;
      return tempState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: So it's working and you're asking if this is the right way to do it?

Comment: It's not working, but Shubham Khatri's answer does the job !

Comment: Looks like it was your `action.payload.val().name` that was the problem then, because the rest of it looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `immutability helper` to assign the new object to the nested state

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

export default function(state={},action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'GET_USER_INFO':
         return update(state, {
             [action.payload.key]: {
                   [Object.keys(state[action.payload.key])[0]]: {
                          $merge: {name: action.payload.name}
                   }
             }
         })
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```